# What causes error "error: '.class' expected"?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, joptionpane

Please help me solve these errors.
These are the errors I'm getting after I have executed the java codes below.

```
/Deposit.java:15: error: '.class' expected
    double results=presentValue(double f, double r ,int n);
                                       ^
/Deposit.java:15: error: ';' expected
    double results=presentValue(double f, double r ,int n);
                                        ^
/Deposit.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
    double results=presentValue(double f, double r ,int n);
                                                    ^
/Deposit.java:15: error: ';' expected
    double results=presentValue(double f, double r ,int n);
                                                         ^
4 errors
```

---

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*This program computes a customers present
deposit to make to obtain a desired future
value
*/
public class Deposit
{
  //Main method
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    //Calling the present value method
    double results=presentValue(double f, double r ,int n);

    //Displaying the present value 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have to deposit: $" +results);
  }

  public static double presentValue(double f, double r, int n)
  {
    //Declaring the input variable
    String input;

    //Taking inputs from the customer
    //Future value
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your desired future value:");
    f = Double.parseDouble(input);

    //Annual Interest Rate
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the annual interest rate:");
    r = Double.parseDouble(input);

    //Number of years
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of years:");
    n = Integer.parseInt(input);

    //Calculating the present value the customer has to deposit
    double p = f/Math.pow((1+r), n);

    //Returning the value to the present value method
    return p;

    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `double results=presentValue(double f, double r ,int n);` you are not passing any vlues here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with function without arguments, since yours doesn't do anything.

```
public class Deposit
{
  //Main method
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double results=presentValue();
    ... // same code
  }

  public static double presentValue()
  {
    double f,r;
    int n;
    ... // same code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever calling a method, never mention the datatype in the arguments of the method.

Your error can be resolved by changing the method calling line,

Make sure that you either pass the value directly as arguments or else declare those values in a variable as shown below.

```
double f = 1.0d; // Just for Example
double r = 2.0d; // Just for Example
int n = 1; // Just assuming

//Calling the method
double results = presentValue(f, r ,n);
```